# Facebook Iframe application authentication?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a Facebook application that runs inside an iframe in the Facebook canvas. For it to work properly I request extended permissions from the user. If the user hasn't authorized the application I send him/her to a login page with the getLoginUrl() method in the PHP SDK.

It works, but it's not pretty. The method sends the user to a landing page before the authentication page. It looks like this:

[image: Facebook Landing Page]

When I click "Go to Facebook.com" I see the actual page for permission requests (I also get right to the permissions page if I print the url, copy it and enter it into a new browser window). How do I make Facebook skip this step when I do the redirect from an Iframe?

My code looks like this (using CodeIgniter and Facebook PHP SDK):

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '{MY_APP_ID}',
  'secret' => '{MY_SECRET}',
  'cookie' => TRUE,
  'domain' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
));

$this->facebook->getSession();

try {
  $this->me = $this->facebook->api('/me');
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  $this->me = NULL;
}

if ( is_null($this->me) ) {
  redirect($this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'offline_access,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos,read_friendlists',
    'next' => $this->config->item('base_url').'fblogin.php?redirect_uri='.$this->uri->uri_string()
  )));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to redirect the parent frame (i.e. _top) rather than the iFrame itself?

Comment: I redirected to a new internal page that used a Javascript to open the login link in a new window. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest :)

Comment: redirecting to the parent frame works. But then it loads my entire application without the surrounding facebook page.

Comment: Redirecting at `_top` is the intended solution and it seems that Facebook expects us to handle the subsequent redirect ourselves. Question 4994286 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994286/facebook-iframe-application-redirect) is discussing that same point.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is set up an INDEX.PHP file with the following

> ```
>     //if user is logged in and session is valid.
>     if ($fbme){
>         //fql query example using legacy method call and passing
> ```
>
> parameter
>               try{
>                   $fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex,
>   pic_square from user where uid=" .
>   $uid;
>                   $param  =   array(
>                       'method'    => 'fql.query',
>                       'query'     => $fql,
>                       'callback'  => 'http://apps.facebook.com/yoursite/'
>                   );
>                   $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
>               }
>               catch(Exception $o){
>                   d($o);
>               }
>           }

Then point your canvas url to http://yoursite.com/INDEX.php

The callback url in the above code which will be in INDEX.PHP sets where to look after permissions are granted.

FBMain.php looks like this

> ```
> //set application urls here
> $fbconfig['http://www.yoursite.com/iframeapp/YOURMAINPAGE.php/']
> ```
>
> =   "http://www.tyoursite.com/YOURMAINPAGE.php/";
>
> ```
> $fbconfig['http://apps.facebook.com/CANVASBASEURL']
> ```
>
> =   "http://apps.facebook.com/CANVASBASEURL";
>
> ```
> $uid            =   null; //facebook user id
>
> try{
>     include_once "facebook.php";
> }
> catch(Exception $o){
>     echo '<pre>';
>     print_r($o);
>     echo '</pre>';
> }
> // Create our Application instance.
> $facebook = new Facebook(array(
>   'appId'  => $fbconfig['APPID'],
>   'secret' => $fbconfig['SECRET'],
>   'cookie' => true,
> ));
>
> //Facebook Authentication part
> $session = $facebook->getSession();
> $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
>         array(
>         'canvas'    => 1,
>         'fbconnect' => 0,
>         'req_perms'=>'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location'
>         )
> );
>
> $fbme = null;
>
> if (!$session) {
>     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href
> ```
>
> = '$loginUrl';";
>           exit;
>       }
>       else {
>           try {
>               $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
>               $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');
>
> ```
>     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
>         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href
> ```
>
> = '$loginUrl';";
>               exit;
>           }
>       }
>
> ```
> function d($d){
>     echo '<pre>';
>     print_r($d);
>     echo '</pre>';
> } ?>
> ```

Hope its a little clearer. It took me a while to figure it out, but I got there, thought I would help.